# Is the Ph.D. fellowship amount for 1st-year students the same in all universities in Israel?

Tags: phd, funding, israel

Just curious!

Is the Ph.D. fellowship amount for 1st-year students the same in all universities in Israel?

If yes, what is the amount?

Comment: Is this information not present on the website of the institution in Israel you are interested in?

Comment: @BryanKrause, No, I haven't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am studying for PhD in Israel, it is not the same even inside universities. The PhD fellowship is determined by the PI's funding or the fellowships that the PhD student can apply for. In our university, the fellowships/salaries are between approximately 6-12,000 NIS.